# CSOM - What happened to `ServerRedirectedPreviewUrl`?

Tags: development, csom

I am using nuget package MIcrosoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM package 16.0.7813.1200

We are migrating from Soap "ows" web services over to the Client CSOM C# code.

One of the fields we used to have was called: `ows_ServerRedirectedPreviewUrl`

But it does not appear in the list item fields, and it doesn't appear in the list item itself.

The only field I can find is `ListItem.ServerRedirectedEmbedUri` but this actually throws errors when I try to fetch that value.

Comment: can you share some sample code you are using to fetch `ServerRedirectedEmbedUri ` , maybe i can help ? Also, the field `ServerRedirectedPreviewUrl` works, as far as i know it will work only in a doc lib.

Comment: I made this its own question to keep these separate https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245587/csom-why-cant-i-fetch-listitem-serverredirectedembeduri