# CSOM - errors when trying to query for ListItem.ServerRedirectedEmbedUri

Tags: csom

I am using nuget package MIcrosoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM package 16.0.7813.1200

I am using the following to fetch all list items and all their metadata from a list:

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = itemPosition;
                    camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><RowLimit>" + config.listViewThreshold + "</RowLimit></View>";
ListItemCollection collListItem = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(collListItem);
clientContext.Load(collListItem,
        items => items.Include(
            item => item.Id,
            item => item.DisplayName,
            item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments,
            item => item.Folder,
            item => item.File,
            item => item.ContentType
            item => item.ServerRedirectedEmbedUri
        ));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

When I include the `item.ServerRedirectedEmbedUri` I get an error message:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 
Field or property "ServerRedirectedEmbedUri" does not exist.
```

I'm guessing the problem is there are some list items that do not have this value. What is the correct way to get this value, but not involve extra network calls?

UPDATE:

Does this require WOPI to be installed? It is *not* installed on my instance.